# Do you have a solution for code efficiency in python?

Tags: python

In python I use a lot of lines like the followings to modify values in array of objects

```
pod[session]['Datas']['Recovery'].xxxxxx = something
pod[session]['Datas']['Next'].xxx = something_else
```

Is there a way to write shorter python code with some kind of shortcut ?
The idea will be to use with something like this:

```
using pod[session]['Datas'] as d:
    d['Recovery'].xxx = something
    d['Next'].yyy = something_else
```

I know it cannot be 'with' and 'using' does not exist ! 
Anything else I don't know ?

Comment: `d = pod[session]['Datas']`; then you can use `d['Recovery'].xxxxxx` and `d['Next'].xxx`.

Comment: Thanks Scoot. Is d a new copy ? I forgot to mentioned I need to modify original datas ? I will make some more tests

Comment: It is not a copy.